# Excessive usage of memory while using ArrayFlatten or Flatten

Tags: list-manipulation, memory, packed-arrays

I have **16 NxN** matrices, where N can be anywhere between **1000-64000**.. Some of them are real and some of them are complex. I want to Reshape then to form a **4Nx4N** matrix. When I try to accomplish this using ArrayFlatten or Flatten[,{{1,3},{2,4}}], this results in a huge spike in memory utilization. For N=2000, that is around 6GB RAM. So for larger N it is going to be astronomically large. However, when I checked the space required to store a RandomComplex[] matrix of the same size was around 2GB, which is still a bit high but understandable with 128bit complex numbers.

I understand that this is probably due to Mathematica **unpacking the array while flattening**, which is what I get when I check with PackedArrayQ[] which returns **false** for the final array.

My question is is there any way to keep the **array packed during flattening**? My idea was the unpacking occurs probably because of different data types, is that the case? If so, then how do I ensure all of them are complex and the resulting matrix remains packed.

I need the matrix in that specific format because I need to calculate inverse and eigenvalues later. Any suggestions which involve not using Flatten but get the inverse of the matrix and eigenvalues are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess some of the matrices are `SparseArray`s? Then in order to prevent the  `SparseArray`s from being converted to dense matrices, make sure that *all* matrices you want `ArrayFlatten` are `SparseArrays` with the same background element. `0`, `0.`, and `0. + 0. I` are *not* the same in this respect. You might have to convert also dense matrics to `SparseArray`.

If you flatten only dense arrays, you also have to make sure first that all matrices are of the same machine number type: Either all `Integer`, double recision reals, or double precision complex numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately,none of the matrices are Sparse so yes I am flattening only dense arrays. How do I ensure all of them are of machine number first? I add +0 I by hand to all the real matrices?

Comment: Thanks, That worked, But what basically goes on? What extra information does Mathematica store that this becomes so large?